# NPOI corrupting xlsm workbook

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, npoi

I am required to write some data into an macro enabled workbook which was developed in 1998, i am using NPOI dotnet core library for this task. I am able to write the values into the excel correctly, however i am seeing that alignment and formatting of the sheets is lost. Screenshots below:

First one shows the file after open the file using NPOI and downloading the same, and second shows the file when it is locally opened.

[image: after download]

[image: when the file is opened locally]

below is the code i am using

```
public XSSFWorkbook OpenExcelFile(string filePath, string tempSavePath)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(tempSavePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                var temphssfwb = new XSSFWorkbook(OPCPackage.Open(filePath));
                temphssfwb.Write(stream);
            }
            XSSFWorkbook hssfwb;
            hssfwb = new XSSFWorkbook(OPCPackage.Open(tempSavePath));
            hssfwb.CreateSheet("casevalidationsheet");
            return hssfwb;
        }
```

Can someone please help me understand why NPOI is ruining the alignment of my excel workbook?

Comment: Unless this is a known issue someone can remember, I doubt anyone can just tell you why. (Maybe the formatting in the original was done with since-deprecated attributes or property names that NPOI doesn't support and just drops?) I think you'll have to unpack the before and after versions and compare the XML to see what's changed, then either dig into NPOI to find out why or ask a more specific question, probably directly to NPOI not here.

Comment: Can you open the original and re-save it with modern Excel, then try again? Or maybe save as xls, reopen and save as xlsx/m again to force it to regenerate the XML?

Comment: npoi does nothing automatically, you have to copy cellstyles and columwidth/height fonts and that stuff manually